# Is there a way to convert numbers to circled numbers in Oracle SQL? ( 1 to ① or 20 to ⑳）

Tags: sql, oracle

Looking for ways to convert numbers to characters.

Comment: It is useful when asking a question on SO to add some context to your question. Tell us what you are trying to achieve, details of any programmimg language you are using and what you have tried so far. A good question attracts good answers.

Answer (score 1):

For SqlServer (which you didn't specify)

```
SELECT NCHAR(numval+9311);
```

Explanation:

- the "enclosed alphanumerics" are at Unicode codepoints 9312 ① through 9331 ⑳. A "numval" of 1 becomes 9312 before passing it to NCHAR
- the [NCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/nchar-transact-sql) function converts from codepoint value to corresponding character

Warning:

- This only works for values from 1 to 20 (there is no "circled number 21" and while there does exist a "circled digit zero" ⓪, that's at 9450)